# How to actually start program minimized in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

Steps i tried to make program (for example: Thunderbird) to load on startup, but minimized:

1. Placed shortcut under: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
2. In a shortcut properties i've checked "minimized"

Rebooted windows, it does start, but MAXIMIZED! Can't make it minimized, just like on MacOS i could set it hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method does not seem to work correctly for me. You could make a scheduled task that runs at user logon with the following batch (.bat) file attached.

`start /min "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla\Thunderbird.exe"`

You would then disable the thunderbird program from running at startup through your appdata path.

Other Options for code:

Save this as a .ps1

```
@echo off
start thunderbird
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('*Mozilla Thunderbird')
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys('(%(" "(n)))')
```

**Make sure when thunderbird opens, the setup email box is not there (client has been configured) and you are not getting prompted for the default mail application.

Comment: Is it necessary to use this code in a batch file? Or scheduler works only with files? This "minimized" thing not working at all for me either.

Comment: the scheduler runs easier if you give it a file to run, rather than straight commands. It is less troubleshooting to feed it a file that you know works. I would open command prompt and paste that command and see if thunderbird opens minimized to test it. You may need to change the file path of the thunderbird exe to reflect your machine's file system

Comment: bah, it's still starting maximized... `start /min "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"`

Comment: this one worked for me, Open powershell and type `Start-Process thunderbird -WindowStyle Minimized` . You can always write this in notepad and save it as a .ps1 and it will have the same functionality as a batch file. I will edit the answer if this one works for you

Comment: Still maximized, lol.

Comment: @AlexanderKim check the answer for latest code block

Comment: It works. first it shows "False" in PS, then after some delay - deactivates the window, isn't there a native way to not show the window at all?

Comment: There was supposed to be, but they didn't work for you haha

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after I changed the syntax order: `Start-Process -WindowStyle Minimized thunderbird`. This seems to be a bug: the prescribed syntax order (see `Get-Help Start-Process`) differs from the one that actually works.