# How to let Task-Manager of Windows 10 start minimized at start-up?

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-manager, command-line-arguments, autostart

I have the Windows task mananger in the start-up/autostart directory, so that it does start at login.

```
C:\Users\[myusername]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
Type: Taskmgr.exe.lnk
target: %windir%\system32\taskmgr.exe
execute in: %windir%\system32
"Execute" is set to minimized ("minimiert")
```

It is just always starting as open windows (normal window, "Normales Fenster") , even if it was minimized before the last logout, and though the start-link is set to minimized.

How could I make the task manager start minimized at start-up? Are there starting-parameters?

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/1346935/how-to-actually-start-program-minimized-in-windows-10

Comment: I'm about to try it. I will answer here in comments, if it works after next start-up.

Comment: @mc10 The .ps1 solution of the question you linked doesn't work. Using the scheduler I don't want to. :/